# extracting a partially matched string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string-matching

I have a folder in which the files are all named like

"12345input789"

"12345output291"

I want to find each pair of files where the start bit ("12345") matches and perform some operation on both of the files

```
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    if "input" in filename:
         input = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
          # how do i extract the output name string here
    else:
        continue
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save all file names in two dictionaries:

```
inputs, outputs = {}, {}
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    if "input" in filename:
         pre, _, post = filename.partition("input")
         inputs[pre] = filename
    elif "output" in filename:
         pre, _, post = filename.partition("output")
         outputs[pre] = filename

# Now you can iterate over all inputs:
for prefix, input_filename in inputs.items():
    output_filename = outputs[prefix]
    do_stuff(input_filename, output_filename)
```

This will of course crash if there is no matching output file for an input file, so make sure that isn't the case, or handle it.

Comment: partition, very nice! so my solution is to sort os.list.dir and iterated over zip(sorted_file_list, range(len(sorted_file_list))). Then the output file is always index + 1, but that only due to the format of the file name... your solution is nice. I think I am going to need this partition function anyway to fetch the correct name for the output.

Comment: Instead of `zip(x, range(len(x)))` use `enumerate(x)` (you'll just have to swap the order of the names you're binding).

Comment: cool, didn't know about that either. maybe i should ask more questions on stack overflow.